# I am trying to get the ACF field default value

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have added a ACF field for torque and set its default value. But the default value is not showing in my existing products.

I want to get the ACF field (torque) default value also in my existing products.

When i add a new product the ACF field (torque) default value is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACF field values are saved as `post_meta` at the exact moment the post gets saved. So they won't be there for posts that have been saved before the ACF field existed (or had a default value).

You have two options now. Either check for the field values for being empty before you output them (and set a default value in that case) by:

```
$field_value = get_field('field_name');
if(empty($field_value)) $field_value = 'default_value';

//Do not use the_field() to output the value but
echo $field_value;
```

or write a script to run once and add the default value to all of the older posts. Something like:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', //Change if other post_type
    'posts_per_page' => -1 
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );


while($products->have_posts()) {
    $products->the_post();

    if(empty(get_field('field_name'))) {
        update_field('field_name', 'default_value');
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already added a default value for torque in ACF fields setting which is displayed in editor when adding a new product.

Comment: I understood that, but that is not going to be set for older posts / products, as I mentioned above. The default value does not apply when **fetching** the field but only when the field is shown in the editor (and has no value).

Comment: So i need to add this script in my function.php in wp_footer hook ?

Comment: No, you can use the first script inside your theme (wherever you're outputting the torque value). The second script should only run once! And you don't need both, but either one.

Comment: So after running the second script once, should i remove the script  ?

Comment: Yes. Depending on the number of posts / products it might run for quite a while (and might even run into timeout or memory issues). If that is the case, add it as extra script to your site.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have one more question for you,  After setting the default value for all the existing products if i want to change the default value of torque field in ACF field setting, is it changes in all the products  ?

Comment: No, it's not. As stated above, setting a default value has absolutely no effect on previously saved posts.

Comment: @AkhilRana Did it work?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the solution.

Comment: Perfect! Glad that I could be of help! :)